# Can a class extend itself?

Tags: scala

I am reading the source code of Spark. I see it seems a class extends itself.

My questions: does it extend itself? If so, what's it called? Why do we do that?

```
class OneHotEncoderModel private[ml] (
    @Since("2.3.0") override val uid: String,
    @Since("2.3.0") val categorySizes: Array[Int])
  extends Model[OneHotEncoderModel] with OneHotEncoderBase with MLWritable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not extending itself. Actually, "extends itself" has no meaning, or one could say all classes extends them-selves.

```
OneHotEncoderModel(...) extends Model[OneHotEncoderModel] with ...
```

means that `OneHotEncoderModel` extends `Model`. And `Model` is type-parametrized with `OneHotEncoderModel`. This construct allows `Model` to have the actual implementing class as a type-parameter and use it.

This can be used, for example, in an abstract api:

```
trait Model[A]{
  def join(other: A): A
}
```

Here, to be a `Model` sub-class, `OneHotEncoderModel` will have to implement `def join(other: OneHotEncoderModel): OneHotEncoderModel`